# How to enable screen sharing when using networkd in netplan?

Tags: networking, vnc, bonding, netplan, gconf

On Ubuntu 18.04, I am configuring a bond of 2 interfaces and using 2 interfaces of another NIC.  Here is my netplan entry:

```
network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
    eno1:
        dhcp4: yes
    eno2:
        dhcp4: yes
    enp129s0f0:
        dhcp4: no
    enp129s0f1:
        dhcp4: no
bonds:
    bond0:
      interfaces: [enp129s0f0, enp129s0f1]
      dhcp4: yes
      parameters:
        mode: 802.3ad
        lacp-rate: fast
        primary: enp129s0f0
        mii-monitor-interval: 100
```

The issue I am having is that when using networkd as the renderer, the connections work fine, but I can not find a way to enable screen sharing for use with VNC.  The Gnome Control Center settings for screen sharing and networking are not active when using networkd instead of NetworkManager.  I attempted to find settings to do this manually and found this Vino setting:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino network-interface 'bond0'
gconftool-2 --set --type=bool /desktop/gnome/remote_access/enabled true
```

but VNC still won't connect. Are there other relevant settings to change?

When I just change networkd to NetworkManager in the configuration above, the bond doesn't work, though I can enable Screen Sharing for the other interface. When I just use 2 network connections with no bonding, then screen sharing won't work after reboot.

Is there a solution or better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you trying to enable the screen-sharing option in GNOME Control Center?

Comment: With the networkd as the renderer, the option to do this in control center is not available. But the 2 options describe when using NetworkManager as the renderer were attempted with Gnome Control Center, but bonding was not working and even when 2 interfaces without bonding were being used, sharing wasn't possible after reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was not able to figure out how to get screen sharing to work with *networkd* as the renderer, but I did figure how to get it working with *NetworkManager*. I was able to get the bond configured using *nmtui*. I followed the instructions [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-configure_bonding_using_the_text_user_interface_nmtui). But even with a properly configured bond, it would only work if the original 1GbE port was not active. Otherwise, Gnome settings would not let me choose the new bond for sharing. To overcome this, I used a method described [here](https://lukas.zapletalovi.com/2019/02/set-the-default-route-via-nmcli.html):

```
nmcli c mod eno1 ipv4.never-default true
nmcli c mod eno1 ipv6.never-default true
nmcli c down eno1; nmcli c up eno1
```

I have verified with a couple of reboots.

EDIT: After checking with *iptraf-ng*, I found that most traffic was going through the original interface.   Executing *route -n* confirmed metric values gave preference to the original metric.  This was fixed with the commands:

```
nmcli connection modify 10Gbond ipv4.route-metric 1
nmcli connection up 10Gbond
```